Basis for co-finite topology of $\mathbb{N}$
I am trying to find a basis for the co-finite topology of $\mathbb{N}$. So I first tried representing elements of the topology which are of the form $\mathbb{N} - (x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n})$ now one thing is these are clearly finite intersections of the elements of the form $\mathbb{N} -(x_{i})$. So to generate it as a union of some elements, I think I need to consider unions where from all participants of the union, the said elements are missing. So essentially, the basis elements kind of look like finite intersections of the complement of singletons. Is there any simpler way to write this out so as to represent the basis? Thank you.

Did you mean cofinite instead? Every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable and cocountable, so the cocountable topology would just be the discrete topology.

And if you actually meant cofinite topology, then complements of singletons form a subbasis, not a basis. I don’t think there are that many ”natural” bases except just the collection of all cofinite subsets, to be honest. (I mean, you could artificially construct one, like the collection of sets that can be written as the union of one cofinal set and one singleton, but that seems more complicated than necessary.)

Ohh am so sorry guys, I meant co finite topology, I will edit asap

@DavidGao yeah I think complements of singletons would form subasis, but their finite intersections would form elements of basis?

"Their finite intersections" is the collection of all cofinite subsets.

There is not a "canonical" choice, nor a nice description. An obvious choice is the space itself. Other than that you can choose for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set $\mathcal{B}_n$ of all the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that are co-finite in $\mathbb{N}$ and lack at least $n$ elements of $\mathbb{N}$.

@Sj2704 Yes, their finite intersections will be a basis. This is true for any subbasis - finite intersections of elements of a subbasis always form a basis. But in this case, as Arturo mentioned, you just get all co-finite subsets, so it’s not particularly interesting.

@DavidGao so essentially I end up getting the topology back itself.. I guess the same thing goes for real line as well. Thank you guys!

@Sj2704 If by “the same thing goes for real line” you meant the real line equipped with co-finite topology, then yes. If you meant the real line equipped with the Euclidean topology, then open intervals form a basis, but that’s definitely not the entire topology.

@DavidGao yes thank you!

$\mathbb{N}$ is countable, so every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is also countable.
Therefore the cocountable topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete and $\mathcal{B}=\{\{x\}:x \in X\}$ is a basis of this topology.

Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I did a major typo where I meant co-finite instead of co-countable. Sorry and thank you!

You're welcome. Yeah... that makes more sense.
